# Flex points are invariant under isomorphism

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, algebraic-curves

Let $C$ be projective algebraic curve. A point $P\in C$ is called a *flex point* if the tangent line $l_P$ of $C$ in $P$ intersect $C$ with multiplicity almost 3.

> Are flex points invariant under isomorphism of algebraic curves?

This doubt come from the fact that, as I understand, every elliptic curve $(E,O)$ is isomorphic to an elliptic curve $(E',O_\infty)$, where $E':y^2=4x^3-ax-b$ and $O_\infty=[0:1:0]$ (this is the Weierstrass equation of the elliptic curve). Now, the problem is that an isomorphisms in the category of elliptic curves must preserve the specified point, but $O$ is an arbitrary point of $E$ and $O_\infty$ is a flex point in $E'$.

Hope someone can clarify this to me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tangent line makes sense only for embedded curves and its intersection makes sense only for plane curves. Are you assuming your curve is a plane curve? Assuming it is, elliptic curves have automorphisms taking a given point to any other point, namely translations in the group law. So, I would say that the answer is no.

Comment: ooh that's true, the fact that Aut(E) is transitive implies that the flex point are not invariant under isomorphism. And, what do you think about the statement about Weierstrass equations? is it true as stated?